# Method Update Angular CLI

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to update a row in my table.

When I click "edit" the action have to redirect me to the detail Form where I also create Users.

This is my listComponent.ts:

```
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {
  employees: Observable<Employee[]>;

  constructor(private employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reloadData();
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.employees = this.employeeService.getEmployeesList();
  }

  deleteEmployee(id: number) {
    this.employeeService.deleteEmployee(id)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.reloadData();
        },
        error => console.log(error));
  }

  updateEmployee(id: number) {
    /*LOGIC*/
  }
}
```

As you can see, the delete method goes to the service's delete so I have to do the same for the update to save my changes also in the server.

This is my service.ts:

```
export class EmployeeService {

  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/employees';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getEmployee(id: number) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`);
  }

  createEmployee(employee: any) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}`, employee);
  }

  updateEmployee(id: number, value: any) {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, value);
  }

  deleteEmployee(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseUrl}/${id}`, { responseType: 'text' });
  }

  getEmployeesList(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}`);
  }
}
```

Here you can see my details.html:

```
<div *ngIf="employee">
  <div>
    <label>Name: </label> {{employee.firstName}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Age: </label> {{employee.lastName}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Active: </label> {{employee.emailId}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Active: </label> {{employee.active}}
  </div>

  <span class="button is-small btn-primary" *ngIf='employee.active' (click)='updateActive(false)'>Inactive</span>

  <span class="button is-small btn-primary" *ngIf='!employee.active' (click)='updateActive(true)'>Active</span>

  <span class="button is-small btn-danger" (click)='deleteEmployee()'>Delete</span>

  <hr/>
</div>
```

How can I write the method redirecting the page in details page and saving all the change?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can refer the below link for your requirement:
[demo link](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rojormdklnk)

You can also visit the tutorial link for detailed explanation:
[Hero tutorial - Angular.io](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3)